# Center a popup div

Tags: html, css, popup, alignment, center

I'm doing a custom gallery for my website and I've got the overview part working with all the thumbnails. When a thumbnail is clicked, the full picture appears on the screen, but I'm having problems aligning it to the center of the screen.

Note that each picture has different dimensions.

This is what I have done so far:

```
.overlay{
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    z-index:1001;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    opacity:.80;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}
.popup {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 8px solid orange;
    background-color: #eee;
    z-index:1002;
    overflow: auto;
}
.galleryentity{
    display: table;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    float: left;
    width: 259px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #2B3039;
    margin-right: 30px;
    position: relative;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 2px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 3px 5px 2px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow:         0px 3px 5px 2px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
.gallerylink{
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<div class="galleryarea">
    <div class="galleryframe">
        <div class="galleryentity" style="background-image:url('pic1.jpg');">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="gallerylink" onclick = "document.getElementById('pic1').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'"></a>
            <div id="pic1" class="white_content"><img class="pic1.jpg"></div>
        </div>
        .
        .
        .
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you are using jQuery and provided that you have images of different dimensions, why don't you try jQuery position option: http://jqueryui.com/position/ . You can position the element relative to screen or any element, left,center,right,bottom,top etc. Give a try

Comment: Hmm, looks complicated... I'll try

Comment: Well, it's not complicated. The documentation makes it complicated. Try this link: http://css-tricks.com/jquery-ui-position-function/ . It's simple as plain english!

Comment: Don't use 0% , 0 is enough.

Comment: @KamleshKushwaha okey, so like this?  `$(".popup").position({
 "my": "center center",
 "at": "center center",
 "of": $("body")
});`

Comment: instead of using $('body'), try centering relative to window

Comment: can u show the code for that please? idk how to use "window"

Comment: Okay, let me add an answer below for you.

Comment: Check the answer, it's just a basic example of centering a div.

Answer (score 2):

CSS approach to center popup :

```
.popup {

      position:fixed;
      /*display: none;*/    /* debug */
      border: 2px solid orange;  /* 8 is too thick ? */
      background-color: #eee;
      z-index:1002;
      overflow: auto;
      top:50%;
      left:50%;
      width:500px;  /* adjust accordingly */
      height:500px;   /* adjust accordingly */
      margin-left:-250px;   /* negative half of width above */
      margin-top:-250px;   /* negative half of height above */

       }
```

Comment: This will not work in my case as each picture has different dimensions. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Why overflow: auto then? Anyways for sideways centering , you can use margin: 0 auto;

Comment: Oh, just some remnant from past code I forgot to remove :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you have to use `body` in your case:
Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/177/

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".checked").position({
        "my": "center",
        "at": "center",
        "of": 'body' //Or window
    });
});
```

Comment: Okay the code "does" something, but its behavior is weird. If I put that code as you have it the picture shows the top left bit of it at the bottom right corner of the screen. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle for it?